# Android NDK, Native app debugging

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am implementing a Native C++ program ( hello world ) w/o JNI

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

I am able to compile, run and attach a debugger using the following set of adb commands:

```
adb.exe -d shell am kill "/data/local/tmp/HellowWorld"
adb.exe -d push ./libs/armeabi/HellowWorld /data/local/tmp/HellowWorld
adb.exe -d shell /system/bin/chmod 0777 /data/local/tmp/HellowWorld

start /B adb.exe -d shell /data/local/tmp/HellowWorld

adb.exe -d push ./libs/armeabi/gdbserver /data/local/tmp/gdbserver
adb.exe -d shell /system/bin/chmod 0777 /data/local/tmp/gdbserver
adb.exe forward tcp:5039 tcp:5039
adb.exe -d shell ps
adb.exe -d shell /data/local/tmp/gdbserver tcp:5039 --attach %PID%
```

I define a new c++ Debug Configuration @ eclipse setting up "*\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gdb.exe*" as the debug client, Then I connect to the gdbserver running on the device

Unfortunetly, none of the breakpoints I set with Eclipse is actually Identified by gdb, info sharedLibrary shows the following where my main exe module is not found ( should it? ):

```
311-interpreter-exec console "info sharedLibrary"

~"From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library\n"
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
~"                        No          /system/bin/linker\n"
                        No          /system/bin/linker
~"                        No          libc.so\n"
                        No          libc.so
~"                        No          libstdc++.so\n"
                        No          libstdc++.so
~"                        No          libm.so\n"
                        No          libm.so
```

This is what I get from adb while setting a break-point:

```
355-break-insert D:/Develop/Android/EclipseProjects/ScreenCapSvc/jni/main.cpp:312
355^error,msg="No symbol table is loaded.  Use the \"file\" command."

(gdb) file
365-interpreter-exec console file
=library-unloaded,id="/system/bin/linker",target-name="/system/bin/linker",host-name="/system/bin/linker",thread-group="i1"
=library-unloaded,id="libc.so",target-name="libc.so",host-name="libc.so",thread-group="i1"
=library-unloaded,id="libstdc++.so",target-name="libstdc++.so",host-name="libstdc++.so",thread-group="i1"
=library-unloaded,id="libm.so",target-name="libm.so",host-name="libm.so",thread-group="i1"
```

I use "*APP_OPTIM := debug*" and "*LOCAL_CFLAGS +*= -gstabs+" at my make files.

Why can't I see my executable module when using "*info sharedLibrary*" ?
 Why can't I set breakpoints on my native NDK executable?

Comment: Well, first, your executable is not a library.  But if your look in your build directory (assuming you used ndk-build) you will hopefully find two versions of your executable - the stripped one that you deployed, and also an unstripped one.  You should be able to point gdb at the unstripped one and get symbols.  Another approach for a temporary need is to objdump the unstripped one, find the address where you want your breakpoint, and set it numerically - though of course at that point, you aren't doing source-level debugging.

Comment: Right, Now I deploy the non-stripped version of the executable, attach gdb, but still, I get the same result... should I specifically refer the client side debugger to the non stripped version? how?

Comment: I'd try the file command in gdb, yes.

Comment: Yup, this resolved the problem, I would have tagged your comment as an answer if it would have been posted as such